# Any problem with my last questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

I got answers.

I click accept.

[What is the cheapest computer (mobo/CPU) that can run windows 11](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16653/what-is-the-cheapest-computer-mobo-cpu-that-can-run-windows-11/16654?noredirect=1#comment27218_16654)

Yet I got a message saying I cannot ask questions anymore.

I wonder why.

I think I asked that one last question in the last month. Nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you hit a [question ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th), which would say, in part:

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from your account because most of your questions need improvement or are out of scope for this site

If that's correct, then my best advice is to follow that post's answer to the best of your ability. The main points, IMHO, are:

- The only way for the ban to be lifted is by contributing positively to the site in other ways.
- Before you do anything else, fix your existing posts!
- Do not delete your posts.
- If you're blocked from asking questions and are unable to improve your existing questions (or your existing questions are all deleted), you'll get the chance to post one new question 6 months after your last question.

The ban takes into account all of your questions, not just the recent ones, so be sure to go back through all of your questions (deleted or not) to see if any can be repaired.

Comment: You're just giving a canned response. I didn't ask any other question in the last month or so.

That is my only question and while it doesn't get many upvotes, it does get answer and is fine.

How can the status of my account "got worse" after that?

Comment: It sounds to me like your most recent question might have been the "one new question in 6 months" that is allowed under this question ban. It's my understanding that the question ban takes all of your previous questions into account.

Comment: Jeff is correct. You did hit the question ban. It looks like there are roughly 15 deleted/downvoted questions on your account out of a total of 34. The most recent deleted one is from 2018, and the bulk of the deleted ones are from 2016 while the scope was being figured out.